# How to randomize a character string in a dataframe

Tags: r, random, character

I have a data frame with 2 columns, each of the class "character". One column is the identifier and the second column consists of letters that I want to randomize.

```
df <- data.frame(identifier=c("number1", "number2", "number3"), 
                 values=c("AGLRJMV", "KTKOXSOCOFMTMSOV", "GTSHH"))

df$identifier <- as.character(as.factor(df$identifier))
df$values <- as.character(as.factor(df$values))
```

I wasn't able to randomize the letters because R doesn't see them as individual characters but as one string. So when I try

```
sample(df[,2])
```

it doesn't randomize the letters.

I tried to split the second column into single columns for each letter but then I wasn't able to join the columns back again because the number of columns is not the same.

So, what I want to have in the end is the following:

```
identifier values 
number1    MVARJGL
number2    OTMCOFMKOSOVKTXS
number3    STHHG
```

Sorry that this might be an obvious question, but I just can't figure it out.. If the question was already answered somewhere else, I'm happy to be directed to that question.

Comment: How exactly do you imagine getting this: `MVARJGL`? We could sample so many times without getting this. Is there some other logic?

Comment: @NelsonGon No I guess, OP is  trying to show one of the many possible outputs we can get.

Comment: Ah! Thanks @RonakShah makes sense.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `stringi` package and its `stri_rand_shuffle` function:

```
require(stringi)
set.seed(1)
values <- c("AGLRJMV", "KTKOXSOCOFMTMSOV", "GTSHH")
stri_rand_shuffle(values)
#[1] "GAJVLRM"          "VOTSXMOTFMOKSCKO" "SHTGH"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can split every character in `values`, then use `sample` to randomize and finally `paste` the string together to get them back as one word.

```
df$values1 <- sapply(strsplit(df$values,""), function(x)
                    paste0(sample(x), collapse = ""))

df
#  identifier           values          values1
#1    number1          AGLRJMV          GJRMVAL
#2    number2 KTKOXSOCOFMTMSOV OSFKMOKCOXMVOTST
#3    number3            GTSHH            HHTGS
```

Comment: awesome, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you !